# Tagging not working to run tests in IntelliJ with JUnit5

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit5

I'm migrating to Junit5 from 4. Can run all tests fine, single tests fine (both via the green play buttons). When I try to run tests tagged with `@Tag` (`@Tag("foo")`), it tells me that no tests are found. In the run configuration, I'm putting `foo` in the "Tag expressions" box, using Test kind: Tags. I've used Categories with Junit4 in the past, and Tags seem like a 1-to-1 replacement, right? I do still have some Category tags in my codebase, as I'm switching over. Several tests tagged with `@Tag` as well. Whether the `@Category` tag is present or not makes no difference in the behavior.

IntelliJ result:

`Running categories [interface org.junit.Test]`

`Process finished with exit code 0`

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your IntelliJ run configuration?

Comment: I’m confused by ˋorg.junit.Testˋ in the error message. Could it be that you’re using this old annotation instead of ˋorg.junit.jupiter.api.Testˋ?

Comment: Yes - that's it. Thanks! submit as an answer, and I'll approve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ˋorg.junit.jupiter.api.Testˋ instead of ˋorg.junit.Testˋ to run JUnit5 tests. Only those can handle the ˋTagˋ annotation.